# SublimeText 2 Ruby formatting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, formatting, sublimetext2

Has anyone found a good Ruby/Rails formatter? There is BeautifyRuby, but it gets strings written like `Q%[]` wrong because it aligns everything to the `[]` and it messes everything up.

Essentially it looks like this from a function auto formatted by beautifyruby:

```
 %x[#{cat_command} &]
    %x[#{join_command} &]
       return newintroname
       end
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: I like/use most of Michael Hartl's setup that he has outlined on Git https://github.com/mhartl/rails_tutorial_sublime_text. He also has a decent tutorial on how he uses Rails with Sublime. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=05x1Jk4rT1A. I haven't tried BeautifyRuby yet.

Comment: cool, did not know about it, will give it a try. thank you!

Comment: Beautify Ruby is buggy. Can't believe it's the only option.

Comment: Just gotta support the dev. :-) It'll be good eventually. Parsing code isn't easy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The current version of [beautifyRuby](https://github.com/CraigWilliams/BeautifyRuby) actually solves this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to use [RuboCop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop) to find all the issues/suggestions/alternatives/good practices in Ruby. It is also available as a Sublime Text plugin.

Ruby Good Practices: https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide